# Header written multiple times while combining csv files using scala and spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Currently I am trying to merge multiple csv files into one single file , with exact same header but different data and they are named as - data_0_1 , data_0_2..

I am using spark and scala to achive this task . Bellow is my code

```html
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Row}
    import spark.implicits._
    
     val INPUT_BUCKET_PREFIX = "fie:/path/data/";
    def getData(tableName: String): Dataset[Row] = {
      spark.read
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
        .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
        .csv(INPUT_BUCKET_PREFIX + tableName)
    }
    
    getData("data*")
    .coalesce(1)
    .write.csv("file:/path/output")
```

Currently, I am able to merge all the files in the folder , but if i keep .option("header", "true") then on every combine i see header is written into outputfile multiple times, which i dont want it to happen , I want header to be written only once into outputfile. How can i achive this ?

Note : if i keep the .option("header", "true") then i see no header is written into outfile

Answer (score 0):

I Am not sure do you have this option in apache-spark. But in pandas I write something like this.

*header=not os.path.exists(filetar1)* - This will create header only once. If the file is Already exists it will not add header

```
df.to_csv(filetar1, sep='|',index=False,encoding='utf-8', mode='a', header=not os.path.exists(filetar1))
```